# How to model different start screens depending on state in a storyboard?

Tags: ios, uistoryboardsegue

When my app launches it needs to display one of 3 different screens depending upon a state variable, therefore there will correspondingly be 3 view controllers.

I'm not sure how to model this situation with storyboards because only one view controller can be the initial VC within the storyboard.

Potentially I could have made the initial VC a navigation controller which pushes one of the 3 other VCs as appropriate, however there's no navigation bar nor need for a navigation controller within my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From whatever controller you want to be the root view controller of the window, you could  present one of these 3 controllers (with animation set to NO) from its viewDidAppear method (maybe viewWillAppear?) using presentViewController:animated:completion:. Then, one of these 3 will be what the user sees first.

Comment: But wouldn't that mean the logic for deciding which controller needs to be presented is placed arbitrarily within another controller. So the VC for screen A for example has knowledge when A,B or C should be displayed. That doesn't seem the right place to put the logic? Its just arbitrary. Have I misunderstood your intention?

Comment: @Mungbeans, well I don't really know what your structure is going to be, so it's hard to tell. I was assuming that this first controller (where you would put this code) would be some other controller, not A, B, or C. If you want A, B, or C to be the root view controller, then you would put the logic in the app delegate, and use it to choose which to set as the window's root view controller.

Comment: I thought you meant this first controller is A, B or C, that's why I was confused.